# How can I find a type defined in an included file?

Tags: c

I'm trying to build XOrg from source, and am running into a compile-time error where a function is being called improperly.  The function's type is defined in some other file included in the file causing the error.  I have no idea what this other file is, so I don't know where this file is supposed to be used.  Is there any way to find this type definition other than looking through every included file?

Comment: If clean sources released by the X.Org project do not compile cleanly for you, then you're doing it wrong.  X.Org sources come with a build system, I presume; are you not using it?  Overall, it's unclear what you mean when you say you don't know *where* a given file is supposed to be used, or why you suppose that knowing its type would inform about that.

Comment: Following from the comment above, the question becomes "What are you trying to build it on..., and how are you trying to build it?"  It's been a few years since I built X from source, but the following the docs provided in the source worked without much trouble on SuSE. If you are hitting a build error, then report the bug [**Xorg Bugzilla Main Page**](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this bash command:

```
grep -R "yourTypeName" *
```

inside the directory where the file is located.

If you have `ack-grep` installed, you can run:

```
ack-grep -cc "yourTypeName"
```

to search all `C` files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools such as `grep` to search all the files in the project.

Searching the include files for your type name as a word (with the `-w` flag) should locate the type declaration quite easily.

`grep` can searching recursively in subdirectories with the `-r` flag.